# How can I declare a sub package so it doesn't conflict with the parent in the environment?

Tags: python

A local package will mask any other package with the same name in the environment.

Steps to reproduce:

```
mkdir pandas
touch pandas/__init__.py
python
>>> from pandas import DataFrame
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name DataFrame
```

If I `cd` into another directory, then I can import, so obviously my package is masking the parent.

I gave an example with `pandas.DataFrame` to illustrate my point. What I'm really trying to do is to create a hierarchy of modules within the same package. But some of my modules are already installed with `pip` and if I try to properly package my new modules, ie with the same package name, I loose access to those modules that are already installed in my environment.

I'd like to keep every module in a separate project/git repository.

PS: I come from `java`

Comment: How about giving them a different name so they don't conflict with other known packages?

Comment: @FlyingTeller that's a quick fix, but it wouldn't make sense anymore: all modules are supposed to belong to same package...

Comment: So you want to have some modules (self developed or from PyPi) like ModuleA, ModuleB as part of some ModuleC? Kind of like creating collections of modules?

Comment: @FlyingTeller I'm trying to package a collection of modules under the same package (namespace), while keeping each module in its own git repo (so each repo is redeclaring the package and contains only one module, but doing so masks the other modules already in the environment)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.` notation for local packages, like in the following:

```
from .pandas import DataFrame
```

By the way to avoid confusion it's better to avoid to have the same name of well-known packages like `numpy`, `pandas`, etc. Otherwise you can do like

```
from mycompany.pandas import DataFrame
```

where you have the following package structure:

```
mycompany/
__init__.py
pandas/
__init__.py
```

so to avoid the package naming overlapping at the root package level.

If you are using a package structure like

```
mycompany/
__init__.py
tests/
__init__.py
```

and you are calling some framework externally, you have two ways:

1) the worst way: manually import the external folder path to the current path:

```
import os
import sys
parentPath = os.path.abspath("..")
if parentPath not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, parentPath)
```

In this example we import the `../` to the current path if it was not imported before.

2) The better way. You use the `__init__.py` to export the `tests/` packages to the outside world:

```
# tests/__init__.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from my_class_A import ClassA
from my_class_B import ClassB
```

so that you will be able to import the class `ClassA` in the external file as usual:

```
# main.py
from tests import ClassA
```

given the following structure:

```
mycompany/
__init__.py
main.py
tests/
__init__.py
my_class_A.py
my_class_B.py
```

(This just to have an idea, of course you must adapt the imports and path to your use case).

Comment: `pandas` was an example to illustrate masking. I'm not working in `pandas`. I'm actually working in `mycompany`, but have separate folders/repositories for each module, hence the masking effect. But I'll try the dot notation.

Comment: No luck with the dot. My repo has two folders: mycompany and tests. I'm actually calling from tests.

Comment: @Samuel understood, updating the answer from inner packages then.